# Why can't the loop read serial numbers be output in order

Tags: python

I am practicing a small python program
Among them,
I hope the result of the program input can be

```
Number:1
Number: 2
Number: 3
```

The numbers are in order
But the python code I wrote
The program can only output errors

```
Number: 3
Number: 3
Number: 3
```

Only 3 numbers
I hope you can provide some assistance
I hope the output of the program is

```
Number:1 Name:James
Number:2 Name:Lisa
Number:3 Name:Sherry
```

My code:

```
ecs=("Number:1","Number:2","Number:3")
for eca in ecs:
    scs=("Name:James","Name:Lisa","Name:Sherry")
for sca in scs:
    print(eca,sca)
```

Thank you everyone!!

Comment: You should explain better what you expect and what you get. Edit the question to explain with properly formatted text.

Comment: Please refer to the markdown guide to format the code: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

```
ecs=("Number:1","Number:2","Number:3")
scs=("Name:James","Name:Lisa","Name:Sherry")
for ecs_item, scs_item in zip(ecs, scs):
    print(ecs_item, scs_item)
```

Output:

```sh
Number:1 Name:James
Number:2 Name:Lisa
Number:3 Name:Sherry
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop ands with eca = Number 3 then you are entering a new loop and printing eca which is number 3.
Also you are creating the second ist in a loop over the first list which doesn't make sense.

solution:

```
ecs=[...]
scs=[...]
for eca,sca in zip(ecs,scs):
   print(eca,sca)
```

Zip makes an iteratable list of pairs with ecs and scs